# How can I write something in connection with a send in photo and actually let it appear?

Tags: discussion

If I send in a photo for the weekly contest how can I let my typed comment letting appear along with the photo? I typed my comment in the part reserved for it, but my text didn´t appear side by side with my photo. It was only my photo that appeared. I deleted the blue part where you should post tour comment, but afterwards, nothing of my comment was to see. Who can help me? The text I want to be shown together with my picture is `Rusty mountains landscape`.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange uses a simple formatting system called "Markdown". You can get help with it by clicking the little ?⃝ in the top right of the editing box when answering — or go straight to https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Specifically, it appears you have typed your comment as the *alt text*. That shows up if the image does not load for some reason, but not otherwise. To have it appear after the image, simply put it... after the image markdown.

Note that many people use the "title" markup to provide a title for their contest entries. There are two different ways to do this, and you can use either:

```
## Like this ##

Or like this
============
```

Which will render as:

### Like this

## Or like this

...and then you can put your image markdown below that.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked! Good to know!